# Is it possible to install LAME on shared hosting?

Tags: shared-hosting, lame

I have a shared hosting account, is it possible to install LAME onto my account? I also don't have SSH access. I want to convert wav to mp3

Comment: As indicated in some answers you should ask your hosting provider first. Depending on what you are planning to do, they could have objections based on performance considerations, or even on legal issues - some companies run screaming when they hear the word mp3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to request that the server administrator installs it.  Most shared hosting providers are used to these types of requests, and are generally accommodating.  However, they may have concerns with you processing large amounts of audio content, and using more than your fair share of system resources.

It's worth asking, at least!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have direct access to the server, I don't really see a way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

That's more of a question for https://serverfault.com/. The best bet is to simply ask your provider.

But unless there is a **policy** against that, you could just replicate a lame binary on your webspace (outside of cgi-bin and htdocs root!) and make it executable (chmod +x via ftp). It's self-contained, so you just need to take care of the architecture (usually x86-64 nowadays, but see phpinfo).

Answer (score 1):

Without having access to the server you will not be able to install LAME on the system. Some providers will take into consideration your request and will install LAME it really depends who your hosting provider is.

If this is a service you want to provide, you can always allow anyone to upload a wav file and when you have time you could convert it and send the user a link with the location of their mp3.